# Accessing activities when the names of those activities is stored in a list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, arraylist

I am working on an app where I have a main activity and in the class of the main activity I have a list which consists of the names of some more activities(or rather names of some more classes) that I need to access.

Now these names are stored in the form of string. So lets say we have a string `s` which gets assigned with the name present at index 0 in the list.

```
s = index[0].
```

Let us also assume name of the activity at `index[0]` is secondactivity. Let say secondactivity is an empty activity that has already been created. So `s` has been assigned with the name secondactivity.

Now that we have the name as `s`, I do something like this :

```
StartActivity(new Intent(mainactivity.this,s.class))
```

In the above snippet `s` is not recognised as a `secondactivity.class` but an error occurs saying that

> s.class not found.

From what I think, the error occurs because `s` is considered as string rather than a class which already exists.

**So is there any solution to get over this problem or maybe a way to convert the string s so that it can be recognised as secondactivity ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to solve this.

1. Use Class.forName(s) instead of s.class.
2. make the list to be a list of classes objects and not strings.